# ¿Por qué al correr el código siempre devuelve la opción falsa?

Tags: python, condiciones, while

El objetivo de mi código es corroborar 3 tipos de direcciones de bitcoin. Deben cumplirse 2 condiciones (extension y comienzo específico) y en función de eso recibir una respuesta, Aquí el código:

```
def run ():
    menu_principal = int(input("""Menú principal:

    1) Ingresar dirección estándar (P2PKH). 
    2) Ingresar dirección de multifirmas (P2SH).
    3) Ingresar dirección SegWit (bech32). 
    4) Salir.

    Elije una opción: """))



    while menu_principal != 4:

        if menu_principal == 1:
            direccion_btc = str(print(input("Ingresa la dirección estándar a corroborar: ")))
            if len(direccion_btc) >= 26:
                if len(direccion_btc) <= 32:
                    if direccion_btc [0:1] == "1":
                        return True
        elif menu_principal == 2:
            direccion_btc = str(print(input("Ingresa la dirección de multifirmas a corroborar: ")))
            if len(direccion_btc) >= 26:
                if len(direccion_btc) <= 32:
                    if direccion_btc [0:1] == "3":
                        return True
        elif menu_principal == 3: 
            direccion_btc = str(print(input("Ingresa la dirección SegWit a corroborar: ")))
            if len(direccion_btc) >= 26:
                if len(direccion_btc) <= 32:
                    if direccion_btc [0:3] == "bc1":
                        return True         
        else:
            break


        if direccion_btc == True:
            print (" La dirección cumple con las condiciones necesarias.")
        else:
            print (" La dirección NO cumple con las condiciones necesarias. Por favor, corroborarla. \n Recuerde que la dirección debe tener una extensión de entre 26 y 32 caracteres. \n Además, debe comenzar con 1 (dirección estándar), 3 (dirección de multifirmas) o bc1 (SegWit). \n")
        menu_principal = int(input("""Menú principal:

    1) Ingresar dirección estándar (P2PKH). 
    2) Ingresar dirección de multifirmas (P2SH).
    3) Ingresar dirección SegWit (bech32). 
    4) Salir.

    Elije una opción: """))
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Explica mejor cual es el error. Agrega los datos con que probaste.

Comment: str(print(input("Ingresa etc, input ya devuelve una cadena y muestra el mensaje, por lo tanto solo es:  input("Ingresa etc.

Comment: La opción de menú si entra correctamente? Si es así algunos de tus if esta dando false:;  Ah, lo que  pasa es que nunca le asignas el true a la variable en vez del return asignale el valor a la variable para entre  al if correctamente. Aparte que direccion_btc no es boolean. Entoces en los returan asigna true otra variable y preguntas por esta ultima

Comment: Al incio del while  inicializa tus variables porque en un nuevo ciclo entrarán con el valor anterior y si no se cumple alguna condición  entrará como si fuera verdadero. Aunque siempre es la linea despues de la opcion. Lo si tienes poner es otra variable que el valor de true o false. No puede ser btc porque se utiliza para otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

No voy a poner todo el código, aunque se puede optimizar, solo una muestra de las líneas de error:

```
direccion_btc = str(print(input("Ingresa la dirección estándar a corroborar: ")))
```

intput devuelve una cadena, la función str() es una redundancia, print() muestra un mensaje pero no devuelve nada! por cierto input muestra el mensaje

corrección:

```
direccion_btc = input("Ingresa la dirección estándar a corroborar: ")
```

y el mismo error se repite en los otros input

Answer (score 0):

### Explicación de lo que pasa

Aparte del gran problema que tienes al hacer `str(print(input(...)))`, que ya destacó @tincopasan, no se por que haces un `return True` si solo estas validando, si haces algún `return` la ejecución terminara, esto por que tu ciclo esta en una función y al poner `return` el código llega hasta ahí y no ejecuta nada mas. Hagamos un ejemplo.

Hacemos un `while` y pones un `return`

```py
while True:
    number = int(input("Ingrese un numero menor que 10: "))
    if number <10:
        return True
```

Esto nos dará un bonito error `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`, pues la sentencia `return` solo es valida para las funciones, y esto no es una función, los ciclos solo aceptan las sentencias `break`, `continue` y `pass` (esta es general). Pero como en tu caso todo tu código esta en una función por lo que no pasará, veamos otro ejemplo.

```py
def test():
    while True:
        number = int(input("Ingrese un numero menor que 10: "))
        if number <10:
            return True
test()
```

En este caso si es valida la sentencia `return` pues el código se encuentra en una función `test()`, pero si le agregamos un `print()` al final y ejecutamos veremos que algo pasa.

```py
def test():
    while True:
        number = int(input("Ingrese un numero menor que 10: "))
        if number <10:
            return True
        print("Gracias por ingresar el numero")
test()
```

Esto *según la lógica que aplicas*, deberá de comprobar el numero y luego imprimir mostrar en el mensaje, pero **NO** debido al `return` la función finaliza en ese punto si se cumple la condición, vamos a ejecutar.

```
Ingrese un numero menor que 10: 1
```

Y ahí termina el programa, ahora vamos a ingresar un numero mayor a `10`.

```
Ingrese un numero menor que 10: 20
Gracias por ingresar el numero
Ingrese un numero menor que 10:
```

Ahora si vemos el mensaje, esto porque el `return` no se ejecutó, además nos seguirá pidiendo el numero.

Al ser una función y retornar un valor este valor será el de la función, veamos un ejemplo.

```py
def test():
    while True:
        number = int(input("Ingrese un numero menor que 10: "))
        if number <10:
            return True
        else: return False #añadimos un else para que no sea infinito

resultado = test()
print(resultado)
```

Y pasara esto:

```
Ingrese un numero menor que 10: 3
True

#probamos otra vez
Ingrese un numero menor que 10: 11
False
```

Como vez el `return` hace que la función devuelva un valor, por lo que si, en tu código, haces

```py
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = run()
    print(res)
```

Veras que sale `True` o `None` por la consola, las funciones retornan `None` cuando no se especifica un `return ...`.

### Solución al problema

Para solucionar tu problema cree una variable que contendrá un valor booleano para saber si es correcto el numero ingresado, además simplifique la forma en que muestras el menú, no pondré todo el código, solo la primera parte.

```py
def run ():
    while True:
        menu_principal = int(input("""Menú principal:

    1) Ingresar dirección estándar (P2PKH). 
    2) Ingresar dirección de multifirmas (P2SH).
    3) Ingresar dirección SegWit (bech32). 
    4) Salir.

    Elije una opción: """))
        validacion = False #iniciamos como False
        if menu_principal == 4: break #verificamos que no sea 4
        elif menu_principal == 1:
            direccion_btc = input("Ingresa la dirección estándar a corroborar: ")
            if  26 <= len(direccion_btc) <= 32: #simplificamos la condicion
                if direccion_btc [0:1] == "1": #verificamos
                    validacion = True  #cambiamos el valor
                    #en caso no se cumpla su valor se quedara como False
        ....
        else:
            break

        if validacion: #por defecto compara si es True
            print (" La dirección cumple con las condiciones necesarias.")
        else:
            print (" La dirección NO cumple con las condiciones necesarias. Por favor, corroborarla. \n Recuerde que la dirección debe tener una extensión de entre 26 y 32 caracteres. \n Además, debe comenzar con 1 (dirección estándar), 3 (dirección de multifirmas) o bc1 (SegWit). \n")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Tu trabajo será adaptar el resto de condiciones a la forma en que te mostré :)